# shrink the vdi file

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

I have a vdi of virtual size 55GB but its actual size is 9.64GB. 
In this vdi file windows 10 is installed. what i want is to remove the unallocated storage from this vdi.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJRj4.png
check this image
i want to get rid of this 38.81GB unallocated storage and need everything same because i needed to convert my vdi file to raw format. 
and raw file will be of 55GB which is unusual to me. 
I tried the compact method but it is not working.
Any solution?

Comment: Is the image configured with a dynamically sized disk? Or a fix 55GB drive?

Comment: Dynamically sized disk

Comment: Will it let you set it to a 10GB fixed drive?

Comment: it gives error when i tried to convert dynamic to fixed..

Comment: Care to share the error with us? Or update your question with the error?

Comment: Also, have a look at `VBoxManage modifymedium --compact`